# Feature importance from tf.estimator.BoostedTreeRegression

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to extracted feature importance from a model built in python using [tf.estimator.BoostedTreeRegressor](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BoostedTreesRegressor).

It looks like a standard way to achieve it is by iterating over all trees in the forest and from the importance of each tree's coefficients to calculate some statistics.

Example in [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html), [xgboost](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-importance-and-feature-selection-with-xgboost-in-python/). I have not found how to address this issue in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment using TensorFlow's Premade BoostedTreeRegressor or Classifier Estimators.